# Enabling autoscrolling in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, scrolling

I'm looking for a way to enable autoscrolling in Windows 10. For example, I'm using a software inside which sometimes I need to scroll down continuously (it updates stuff only if I scroll down), for this reason I need to scroll down automatically without touching the mouse wheel.

Comment: "it updates stuff only if I scroll down" is this a log file you're monitoring?

Comment: Hello @spikey_richie it's a different software, I use it for graphics.

Comment: And the up/down or PgUp/PgDn keys won't do the job?

Comment: Hi @DrMoishePippik I need to do it without touching mouse and keyboard so that I can go away from the PC.

Comment: Put cello tape on the keys.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik fantastic:) btw if there is a non mechanical way I prefer that one.